# Need some help with trigonometry. Inverse functions.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Can someone help me to solve these examples?

Evaluate:

> $$A= \text{arccot}\bigl(\tan\biggl[\frac{4\pi}{5}\biggr]\bigr)\;\; \text{and}\;\; B=\sin\bigl(\arctan\biggr[\frac{-3}{7}\biggr]\bigr)$$

Comment: Let's take the first one. It asks to evaluate
$$
A = \cot^{-1}{\tan{(\frac{4 \pi}{5})}} \Rightarrow \cot{A} = \tan{\frac{4\pi}{5}}
$$
what did you try after this?

Comment: @MattiP. Maybe it makes sense to change tan into cot? So, the answer is  cot(pi/2-4pi/5)

Answer (score 0):

I just signed up StackExchange today, and this is my first answer. Sorry, cause I can't use MathJax code properly. I will solve A first...
If $0\le A\le2\pi$, then there are 2 solution for A

$cotA = tan{(4\pi/5)}$ 
$cosA/sinA = sin(4\pi/5)/cos(4\pi/5)$ 
$cosA.cos(4\pi/5) = sinA.sin(4\pi/5)$ 
** Use trigonometry multiplication formula ** 
$1/2(cos(A+4\pi/5)+cos(A-4\pi/5))=-1/2(cos(A+4\pi/5)-cos(A-4\pi/5))$ 
$cos(A+4\pi/5)+cos(A-4\pi/5)=-cos(A+4\pi/5)+cos(A-4\pi/5)$ 
$cos(A+4\pi/5)=-cos(A+4\pi/5)$ 
$2cos(A+4\pi/5)=0$ 
$cos(A+4\pi/5)=0$ 
$cos(A+4\pi/5)=cos(\pi/2)$ 
$A+4\pi/5=\pi/2$ 
$A=-3\pi/10=17\pi/10$, **this is the first solution**. 

Now back to $cos(A+4\pi/5)=0$,

because not only $cos(\pi/2)=0$,

$cos(3\pi/2)$ also equals $0$, so we should substitute $cos(3\pi/2)$ to $0$ too... 

$cos(A+4\pi/5)=cos(3\pi/2)$ 
$A+4\pi/5=3\pi/2$ 
$A=7\pi/10$, **this is the second solution** 
Hope this help